# Why doesn't my little cron job find the shell command?

Tags: cron

```
 34 7 * * * test_cron > /tmp/stdout.log 2> /tmp/stderr.log
```

And my executable 'test_cron' contains:

```
echo "Test cron job ..."

now=$(date)
echo "Cron job update completed at $now"
```

But when it executes, the stderr is below:

```
tmp % tail /tmp/std*           
==> /tmp/stderr.log <==
/bin/sh: test_cron: command not found

==> /tmp/stdout.log <==
```

Does it mean it can't find the /bin/sh? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can check

1. Does the `test_cron` have an executable flag? If it doesn't you can run the following command in the dir where the script exists.

```bash
chmod +x test_cron
```

2. Does the `test_cron` script exists in the `$PATH`?

PS: I would recommend writing the absolute path to your test_cron script in your cron config. In this case you won't need to add the script to your `$PATH`

Comment: ls -lah test_cron: -rwxr--r--, so it has executable with my username.

Comment: Yes. Absolute path solved the problem and thanks.